# How much space does a Linux software RAID1 REALLY occupy on its component devices?

Tags: linux, partitioning, raid, software-raid

A precise answer to this question is important when shrinking the array and its components.

As an example, I have a RAID1 `/dev/md0` set up on two partitions, `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1`.
Both `fdisk` and `/proc/partitions` agree that these partitions are 248832 KiB (497664 sectors, exactly 243 MiB).
The array was most likely created using Debian installer to fill the available space.

`mdadm --detail /dev/md0` reports:

```
        Array Size : 248640 (242.81 MiB 254.61 MB)
     Used Dev Size : 248640 (242.81 MiB 254.61 MB)
```

In `/proc/partitions` the size of `/dev/md0` is also reported as 248640. The filesystem present on `/dev/md0` also claims to occupy exactly this many 1 KiB blocks.

To summarize, the bounds are:

- upper: 248832 KiB (size of each component device)
- lower: 248640 KiB (size of contained filesystem)

Difference: 192 KiB.

Some of the 192 KiB are obviously needed for the array metadata (superblock and whatnot).

The question is now - how many sectors precisely does the array really occupy on the component devices?
In other words, how do I compute the smallest possible size for `/dev/sd[ab]1` that will keep the array intact?

Whatever "Used Dev Size" means above (the internets are not sure), it clearly does *not* take the metadata into account.

Looks like `mdadm --examine /dev/sda1` reveals some more data:

```
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
[...]
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2
[...]
 Avail Dev Size : 497408 (242.88 MiB 254.67 MB)
     Array Size : 248640 (242.81 MiB 254.61 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 497280 (242.81 MiB 254.61 MB)
    Data Offset : 256 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=176 sectors, after=128 sectors
```

Especially the "Avail Dev Size" looks interesting, since it seems to be exactly 128 KiB larger than the array size (per component).
This roughly matches the vague "about 128Kb of space at the end of the drive for the RAID superblock." mentioned in --size description in the mdadm man page, if one assumes that the author actually meant "KiB" where they wrote "Kb".

But I'm rather reluctant to assume this is the number I'm looking for.

Comment: With respect to the context; a fairly technical man-page, I'd expect "Kb" to be "kilobits" and noting else. KB on the other hand would translate to the binary oriented term (i.e. using base 2 "kilo").

Comment: https://documentation.suse.com/sles/12-SP4/html/SLES-all/cha-raid-resize.html#sec-raid-resize-decr-raid

Comment: The SuSE page is rather imprecise, and note they say KB rater than Kb: [...] to a size that is slightly larger than the size you set for the segment size. The size should be a multiple of the chunk size and allow 128 KB for the RAID superblock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome Marcin to SuperUser.

It depends on the metadata format.

With the old 0.9 format, it is quite simple, as documented in the manpage for `md(4)`:

> The common format — known as version 0.90 — has a superblock that is
> 4K long and is written into a 64K aligned block that starts at least
> 64K and less than 128K from the end of the device (i.e. to get the
> address of the superblock round the size of the device down to  a
> multiple  of 64K  and  then subtract 64K).  The available size of each
> device is the amount of space before the super block, so between 64K
> and 128K is lost when a device in incorporated into an MD array.

With the new 1.x format, it is more complicated. The same manpage reads:

> The new format — known as version 1 — has a superblock that is
> normally 1K long, but can be longer.  It is normally stored between 8K
> and 12K from the end of the device, on a 4K boundary, though
> variations can be stored at the start of the device (version 1.1) or
> 4K from the start of the  device (version 1.2).

Your RAID array uses a version 1.2 superblock. According to the manpage, you know the superblock is stored at 4kiB from the start of the device, and that it is “normally 1kiB long, but can be longer”. Hence, the data must start at least at 5kiB from the start of the device, but that does not tell you where exactly.

In fact, with version 1.x superblock, where the data starts is known
as the data offset. The manpage for `mdadm(8)`, describes the
`--data-offset` parameter:

> Arrays with 1.x metadata can leave a gap between the start of the
> device and the start of array  data.  This gap can be used for
> various metadata.  The start of data is known as the data-offset.
> Normally an appropriate data offset is computed automatically.
> However it  can be useful to set it explicitly such as when
> re-creating an array which was originally created using a different
> version of mdadm which computed a different offset.

It hints you that the data offset varies.

In your case, `mdadm --examine` reports that the data offset is 256 sectors.

It also reports you have 128 sectors of unused space after the data. I guess this is because the data size has to be a multiple of the chunk size (512kiB by default, according to the manpage of `mdadm`).

Hence, you have 256 sectors before the data (which include the superblock, other things and 176 sectors of unused space), your data, and 128 sectors of unused space after the data.

You can reduce your partition by 128 sectors if you wish. You might also try to run `mdadm --grow` to change the data offset, but it is not supported yet on my system (mdadm 4.1, linux kernel 5.10.140).

Hope this helps.

Comment: 256 sectors before the data + 497280 sectors (=248640 KiB *2) of data + 128 sectors of unused space after the data => equals 497664, while the device size is 497408 sectors

So something does not seem to sum up here :-/

Comment: You wrote “Both fdisk and /proc/partitions agree that these partitions are 248832 KiB (497664 sectors, exactly 243 MiB).”; I think it does sum up.

Comment: @MarcinOwsiany As for the “Avail Dev Size”, which is 497408 sectors, it includes both the data and the unused space after the data: 497408 = 497280+128.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely correct @user2233709!